# Specifying cursor options when returning a Stream in Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring Data MongoDB (spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb from Spring Boot `1.5.2.RELEASE`) and MongoDB `3.4.9` and have defined a repository defined that looks like this:

```
interface MyMongoDBRepository extends CrudRepository<MyDTO, String> {
    Stream<MyDTO> findAllByCategory(String category);
}
```

I then have a service, `MyService` that interacts with this repository:

```
@Service
class MyService {
    @Autowired
    MyMongoDBRepository repo;

    public void doStuff() {
        repo.findAllByCategory("category")
            .map(..)
            .filter(..)
            .forEach(..)
    }
}
```

There's quite a lot of data in the database and sometimes this error occur:

```
2018-01-01 18:16:56.631 ERROR 1 --- [ask-scheduler-6] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler : org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 
Query failed with error code -5 and error message 'Cursor 73973161000 not found on server <mongodb-server>' on server <mongodb-server>; 
nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCursorNotFoundException: 
Query failed with error code -5 and error message 'Cursor 73973161000 not found on server <mongodb-server>' on server <mongodb-server> 
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:77) 
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2135) 
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.access$1100(MongoTemplate.java:147) 
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$CloseableIterableCursorAdapter.hasNext(MongoTemplate.java:2506)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115) 
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) 
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) 
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) 
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) 
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) 
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) 
at com.mycompany.MyService.doStuff(MyService.java:108) 
at com.mycompany.AnotherService.doStuff(AnotherService.java:42) 
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2026.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) 
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) 
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) 
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCursorNotFoundException: Query failed with error code -5 and error message 'Cursor 73973161000 not found on server <mongodb-server>' on server <mongodb-server> 
at com.mongodb.operation.QueryHelper.translateCommandException(QueryHelper.java:27) 
at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.getMore(QueryBatchCursor.java:213) 
at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.hasNext(QueryBatchCursor.java:103) 
at com.mongodb.MongoBatchCursorAdapter.hasNext(MongoBatchCursorAdapter.java:46) 
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:145) 
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$CloseableIterableCursorAdapter.hasNext(MongoTemplate.java:2504) ... 24 more
```

I've read at various places that when using the vanilla MongoDB Java client you can configure the MongoDB cursor to either have no timeout or set a batch size to hopefully mitigate this.

If this is the way to go, then how can I supply cursor options when returning a `Stream` from Spring Data MongoDB?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your error is occurring because you are processing the stream too slowly, so the cursor is timing out before you get to the next batch.

Batch size can be set on the [Spring Data Query object](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Query.html), or on a Repository using the [@Meta](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/Meta.html) annotation. For example:

```
Query query = query(where("firstname").is("luke"))
    .batchSize(100);
```

Or when using repositories:

```
@Meta(batchSize = 100)
List<Person> findByFirstname(String firstname);
```

See [Spring Data MongoDB documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.query.additional-query-options) for more details.

The cursor timeout can also be disabled on a per query basis using the same configuration. e.g. `@Meta(flags = {CursorOption.NO_TIMEOUT})`.

The cursor timeout cannot be changed on a per-query basis. That is a server configuration. You need to use the [cursorTimeoutMillis](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/index.html#param.cursorTimeoutMillis) server parameter to change that server-wide.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me debugging my issue! In my case, the batch size is small, but one of the step in a batch at rare cases could hang and consume large amount of time for some external reason. So we got the same error.

Comment: With Spring Boot 3: `@Meta(cursorBatchSize = 100)`, see [@Meta Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/4.0.0/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/Meta.html)

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the two options you mentioned.

1. Batch size, You cannot set batch size using Repository class. You can do it using `MongoTemplate`. Something like this

   ```
   final DBCursor cursor = mongoTemplate
           .getCollection(collectionName)
           .find(queryBuilder.get(), projection)
           .batchSize(readBatchSize);
      while (cursor.hasNext()) {
          ......
          ......
       }
   ```

But to use MongoTemplate you need to create a Custom Repository.

2. Regarding Cursor timeout. You can do something like this

   ```
   @Configuration  
   public class MongoDbSettings {

       @Bean
       public MongoClientOptions setmongoOptions() {
           return MongoClientOptions.builder().socketTimeout(5000).build();
       }
    }
   ```

There are many other options(`heartbeat`, `connectiontimeout`) you can set for Mongo. You can set those properties in your application.properties file, and then bind it using `@Value` in the above class and set(instead of hardcoding).
Unfortunately, spring-boot doesn't provide any way to specify these in `application.properties` file

Comment: 1) batch size can be set even when using a Repository. Use the @Meta annotation.
2) socketTimeout has nothing to do with cursorTimeout. Cursor timeout can only be set on the server using the cursorTimeoutMillis server parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to supply cursor options when returning a Stream from Spring Data MongoDB. The possible reason for this exception is how your service read data from Mongo. Possible reasons:

1. You are sharing a single cursor across multiple threads
2. You are requested too many elements at once
3. Load balancer before Mongo server

See [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1010) Jira topic's comments for some ideas an direction applicable to your application.