# How to enable batch inserts in spring boot with mongo database

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm having a spring boot application connected with Mongo DB now I want to enable spring batch how can I manage this withi spring data Mongo

What I saw with Spring data JPA

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
```

Now how can I configure this with spring data mongo

Comment: one of options you can find here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072977/specifying-cursor-options-when-returning-a-stream-in-spring-data-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072977/specifying-cursor-options-when-returning-a-stream-in-spring-data-mongodb)

Comment: Thanks so much @ArmenArzumanyan that was really help fully